# How to view "Events per second" in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am building an alert using Elasticsearch and I need to access the data for one of the logstash nodes for how many events it is receiving per second. On the Monitoring (formally Marvel) tab, this information is readily available in graph format. Is there anyway to get that same information using an ELK API aside from scripting something?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Logstash Metrics filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html.)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will check this out. Does this mean that there is no built in way to access this information?